# How can I email a 750GB file by tomorrow?

Tags: file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I send super large files directly to another computer in the Internet for free?](https://superuser.com/questions/211912/how-can-i-send-super-large-files-directly-to-another-computer-in-the-internet-fo)

This is a huge DVD file that I need to deliver digitally to a distributor in another country. Is it even possible to send such huge files? I can't think of a service that will handle files this big.

Comment: `750GB / connection speed = minimum hours it'll take`. Have you considered FedEx next-day air delivery and an external hard drive?

Comment: If you do calculate to get an estimate, be very careful of units. Internet speed is usually advertised in **bits** per second, while data is measured in **bytes**.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=750+GB+at+50+mbps

Comment: If this file is ultimately destined for a DVD, then it will be maximum 9GB once it gets there.  Have you considered doing the transcoding first before sending it (assuming this is video data)?

Comment: *> If you do calculate to get an estimate, be very careful of units.*   Indeed. Imagine thinking everything is set, only to discover it will take *eight* times longer.

Comment: Wait a minute, I just noticed that the question is asking how to ***email*** 750GB. I guess the answer is **you don’t!** If on the other hand the question is how to *transfer* 750GB in a day…

Comment: Obligatory XKCD reference: http://xkcd.com/949/

Comment: I would say you should have started yesterday.

Comment: This is also hugely dependent on the countries involved... I spent 10 hours uploading 1.2GB from China to a U.S. server over the weekend, then my brother (also in U.S.) spent 8 minutes downloading it from that server... >_>

Comment: it cant be `a` DVD....its like 75 DVDs...
do you mean 750MB??

Answer (score 9):

Using a large hard drive, and using a courier (maybe with next day delivery) is really your only solution considering the time/volume of information. Even then, your 'latency' would depend on when the next delivery time is, and what the country is. In addition this is likely to be more reliable, assuming you packed up the drive properly.

You have the right idea on using disks, but considering the volume density and other aspects, a HDD would be the best choice. Chances are it'll be at your customer's doorstep before you're partially done with the massive upload of doom, let alone downloading.

Considering the sheer size of the file, any online file transfer would/should need to be point to point, and fault tolerant. rsync between them and you might work for example. Compressing the files (ideally with some format that allows for parity files in case some chunks go bad) may work as well.

And of course, you could use bitorrent, get a few vps's to act as additional seeds with parts of the files to speed stuff up and do that. NO online option meets the bandwidth of a truck full of hard drives tho.

Comment: I have the feeling that we are on the verge of a bunch of *bandwidth-of-pigeon* jokes and such…

Comment: Too late. Though its trucks. You'd need a lot of birds for IPOA, and the restricted size of a datapacket makes it unsuitable for bulk transfers.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Not really, a 64GB SDXC card is a few grams.  I reckon you could do this with 11 pigions, perhaps double for redundancy.

Comment: I wonder how long each hop has to be as well though. (Look what you did! ;p). You'd need to also have planned roosts, switchovers... its just too complicated for anything larger than a MAN.

Answer (score 8):

Do you have a connection that can even upload a file that fast (you need a continuous upload speed of at least 70 Mbps<sup>**1**</sup>, assuming that by tomorrow means 24 hours away)? If not, then there is nothing to talk about. If you do, you will need to purchase some space on some service (google drive, dropbox, etc). Make sure they will allow you to upload at the required speed.

Another alternative is that one of you (with the higher upload speed) create an FTP server using [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server) (or similar) and the other downloads it.

As an aside, how could a DVD ever hold that much data?

---

<sup>**1**</sup>
 [image: math]

Comment: he OBVIOUSLY means a 16 layer blu ray disk :)

Comment: *> As an aside, how could a DVD ever hold that much data?*   A few hours of uncompressed high-def video?

Comment: @Synetech, on one DVD? Never even heard of a DVD with that kind of capacity (or even order of magnitude)

Comment: He didn’t specify a disc, he said a *DVD **file***. He could simply have meant video. Besides, he didn’t say there was only *one* disc.

Comment: @Synetech, maybe I am being too precise, but "a huge DVD" means one

Comment: He didn’t say “huge DVD”, he said *huge DVD **file***.

Comment: @Synetech, this is a little silly, but what the heck does that even mean?

Comment: What does what mean? He has a video file; maybe an `.iso`, maybe a `VIDEO_TS` folder, maybe `.mpg` or `.vob`… `.avi`…

Comment: Either that or maybe his huge DVD needs to be taken literally. Maybe the DVD is 12 meters in diameter.

Comment: @kobaltz In that case, it may be faster to physically roll the DVD to its destination.

Comment: Disc and File. Both four letter words. Coincidence? I think not.

Answer (score 6):

Unless both you and your recipient, and all the hubs in between have a connection like this.

[image: Highspeed Connection]

Which makes it take about **~6000 seconds**, which is about 100 minutes.

I'm afraid it's going to take *a very long time*.

---

Even if you are one of our top users (not me), you would have a connection like this:

[image: Typical connection]

**16304 seconds**, which is about 271 minutes.

---

Now, our connections are like a factor 10 slower, so that means it would take like **3000 minutes**. Which means about 50 hours if you have 30 Mb/s (not MB/s). So, perhaps if you have an advertised 100 Mb/s you can do it in under a day; if you don't have such high speed connection available it will most likely take you two. **You might be better off sending a hard disk**, if you don't want to deal with checking for corruption and all that.

If it's text, **compression** can cut a huge part of the size of it. Other than that, it depends on your speed, error correction and availability...

Comment: 750GB of text? That would border insanity. I'm not even sure what kind of data is being dealt with, but it probably needs to be processed before being sent (sort of like those people uploading 15GB video files to youtube).